# Correct zoom range values for jquery flot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, plot

I have given a zoom range to the graph using zoomRange function through which I can limit the range of zoom in and zoom out. It takes two values which such as `zoomRange[min, max]` for xaxis and yaxis.

The problem I am facing is what are the correct values that I should give to this range. When I give range as given in the documentation which is `zoomRange[0.1, 10]` then zoom simply does not work and when I give some random value then the graph zoom more on yaxis then the xaxis or vice versa.

The value I have given to the graph are as follows -

```
xaxis: { 
        mode: "time",
        zoomRange: [240000, 2550000]
        },
yaxis: { 
        zoomRange: [2, 22]
       }
```

These values are arbitrary values and thus does not perform well for different amount of data.

I want the values through which the zoomRange can perform perfect for any type of graph I plot.

P.S.: I asked this question months ago, still didn't overcome the problem

Comment: Did you learn anything more, I don't like how the zooming works so maybe i just have the range wrong? If i zoom out , and the try to zoom in again I never find the series again... they are out side the chart range i guess.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that a good zoom behavior is to set the panRange to the minimum and maximum of the data range, +/- ~10%.  Then set the zoomRange to the smallest increment of your data*some-small-integer and null for the upper zoomRange value (the panRange will limit how far you can zoom out, so the upper zoomRange limit isn't really necessary).  For example, if you have stock price data ranging from $35-$85 and hourly intervals for your x data, then you could do:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    // set the lowest (zoomed all the way in) range on the x axis to 2 hours
    zoomRange: [7200000, null],
    // set the pan limits slightly outside the data range
    panRange: [min_time*0.9, max_time*1.1]
},
yaxis: {
    // set the lowest range on the y-axis to 5 dollars
    zoomRange: [5, null],
    // set the pan limits slightly outside the data range
    panRange: [30, 90] 
}
```

So with this example, you will be able to zoom all the way down to a $5 dollar increment over a 2 hour period.  When you zoom all the way out, you will end up with the ranges specified in the panRange parameters.

Setting the minimum zoomRange lower will allow you to zoom in more (but considering the granularity of the data, doesn't make much sense).  And setting the panRange limits wider will allow you to zoom out more.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if you figured this out. Anyway, I found this:

> "**zoomRange**" is the interval in which zooming can happen, e.g. with
>   zoomRange: [1, 100] the zoom will never scale the axis so that the
>   difference between min and max is smaller than 1 or larger than 100.
>   You can set either of them to null to ignore.

here: http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.navigate.js?r=186